# Activate inactive RAID6

Tags: ubuntu, mdadm, ubuntu-22.04, raid6

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

I have mdadm RAID6 with 4 drives. This is a minimal test configuration before extending it to target 8 drives. RAID was in working state:

```
cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid6 sde1[3] sdd1[2] sdc1[1] sdb1[0]
      7423068160 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 0/28 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

RAID is added to `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/md0 /mnt ext4 nofail 0 2
```

RAID is registered in `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`

```
# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=storage-1:0 UUID=980d97dd:ea196ee0:2f803457:f160f2d0
```

`initramfs` was rebuilt and system rebooted - confirmed that RAID is operational.

Testing recovery procedure now - to simulate device failure physically disconnected one drive (from turned off PC). After the boot RAID6 in inactive:

```
cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : inactive sdb1[1](S) sdd1[3](S) sdc1[2](S)
      11134602240 blocks super 1.2
       
unused devices: <none>
```

I understand that RAID6 maintains data integrity with single drive removed, so was expected to find it active.

**Do I misunderstand how the RAID6 works or it is necessary to re-activate RAID after simulated failure?**

Comment: Did you test rebooting before removing one of the drives, to ensure that the RAID6 came up properly in the normal case?

Comment: Is your array declared in `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`?

Comment: Do you have an `initramfs` as part of the boot process? If so you must rebuild it so it has the latest copy of `mdadm.conf` available at boot time

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1825165/edit) to provide the requested information, so I can delete my comments. Do not respond here in comments.

Comment: Oh by the way, RAID5 handles a single drive failure but RAID6 copes with two failures. If you're using RAID6 across four drives you might be better with RAID10

Comment: Does it help you : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/342407 - It's necessary to activate the RAID (array) manually if you perform the failure test when machine is powered off. If you want to simulate a failure on a drive machine UP, you can use `mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sdX1` where X is the partition you want to fail.

Comment: With this method, your array should stay `active`. FYI, `RAID 6` tolerance is 2 failed drives. To re-add your drive after the test : `mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdX1` - Does my answer is fine for you ?

Comment: @hidigoudi yes as suggested in that article it starts RAID in read-only mode - problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @hidigoudi, the [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/342407) is:

> If mdadm cannot find all the parts of an array when assembling it, it
> won't automatically activate it for use. You can manually activate it
> with the command mdadm --run /dev/md3. It may start up in read-only
> mode, in which case you can put it in read-write mode with mdadm
> --readwrite /dev/md3.